# Create a regular expression with the tags?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

There are three lines on the pages (000) 000-0-000 and +00 (000) 000-00-00 so I wrote a regular expression that searches for them `/([\+]?[0-9]+\s)?[\(][0-9]+[\)]?[\s][0-9-]+/`, but the third string is enclosed in tags `<strong>(0000)</strong><span>00-00-00</span>` how to modify the expression to come across and the third row?

```
function PhoneReplace(){
            var src = $('body').html().replace(/([\+]?[0-9]+\s)?[\(][0-9]+[\)]?[\s][0-9-]+/g, '098 907 23 42');
            $('body').html(src);

        };
```

tags can not be deleted, I must be replaced

Comment: Don't catch that with regular expressions. Instead, modify the string before you apply your phone number expression, i.e. remove the tags.

Comment: I need to replace the numbers, leaving the formatting tags

Comment: Don't try to re-render the whole document by setting `innerHTML`. It's better to mark out phone numbers and replace only those in the DOM. Btw, why is this question tagged PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = '<strong>(0000)</strong><span>00-00-00</span>';
var n = '', result;
var regex = /(\+?\d+)/g;
while ((result = regex.exec(s))) { 
  n += result[1];
} 
document.writeln(n);
```

Check this code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2nBvw/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't catch that case in your existing regular expression. Instead, modify the string before you apply your phone number expression, i.e. remove the tags. There are many ways to do so, e.g. use a DOM parser, regexes might not be the best tool for that. You could do

```
var results = input.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,"").match(myPhoneNumberExpression);
```

to remove all tag-like things.

Comment: tags can not be deleted, I must be replaced

Comment: Who talked of "*deleting tags*"? Or do you mean that you want to replace block-element-tags with whitespaces?

Comment: replace the contents of the tags on the same order of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.body.innerText` or `document.body.textContent` to get at the textual content (without tags) of the HTML and you can then apply your phone# regular expression.

If the textual content doesn't help, then [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) explains several (hacky) ways to remove tags from a string of HTML.